Extract 12 character from a string impala query
I have a column that contains productID,catalogID and organization.
For example 1000002121US200100 contains 1000002121=product ID, US20=catalogID, 01=product channel and finally 00=sales area.
Is there a way I can split this up using the position of the string.  I can do a left('fieldname',10) to get the first 10 characters which gives me the product ID.  How do I extract next 4 characters into a separate column and so on?
I have tried using left() function, split_part and regex_extract

Try the SUBSTR function. https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/asf-site-html/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__substr

Wouldn't that work?
-- To get the productID (first 10 characters)
SELECT LEFT(fieldname, 10) AS productID,

-- To get the catalogID (next 4 characters)
SUBSTRING(fieldname, 11, 4) AS catalogID,

-- To get the product channel (next 2 characters)
SUBSTRING(fieldname, 15, 2) AS productChannel,

-- To get the sales area (last 2 characters)
SUBSTRING(fieldname, 17, 2) AS salesArea

FROM your_table;


Thank you, I forgot about the substring function.  It worked perfectly
